# Update select options based on optgroup not working in IE

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

I've built a custom store front for a client and he's having issues with my `select` dropdown menus updating. I say he because it works as expected for me in modern browsers and even IE7+, so I'm not quite sure how to troubleshoot the issue.

When the user changes the product dropdown, the delivery options dropdown updates to reflect the options for that product. The issue he's seeing is that it simply doesn't change the options (which makes the checkout fail - I know, I'm working on the non-JS/JS-failed fallback as well, but I'd like to get the JS version working too).

Here's the (truncated) HTML for my dropdowns:

```
<select id="product" name="product">
    <option value="1">3 Man Chess Primary Set includes FREE shipping in Contiguous USA. [ $49.95 ]</option>
    <option value="999">Digital Download [ $0.99 ]</option>
</select>

<select id="location" name="location">
    <optgroup label="3 Man Chess Primary Set includes FREE shipping in Contiguous USA." id="1">
        <option value="1">Contiguous U.S.A.  (UPS Ground)</option>
        <option value="2">Alaska &amp; Hawaii (Priority Mail)</option>
        <option value="3">Canada (Priority Mail)</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Digital Download" id="999">
        <option value="50">E-mail</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

I loop through the select's optgroups and set the HTML within each to a variable named by ID (this is the content that changes). The Product ID and Location optroup ID match.

```
var amtList = Array {

    [ ... ]

    optgroups: Array[1000] {
        1: "<option value="1">Contiguous U.S.A.  (UPS Ground)</option>
            <option value="2">Alaska &amp; Hawaii (Priority Mail)</option>
            <option value="3">Canada (Priority Mail)</option>"
       999: "<option value="50">E-mail</option>"
}
```

This is the code that actually does the switching:

```
$("#product").change(function(){
    $("#location").html( amtList["optgroups"][ $(this).val() ] );
});
```

Here's the specs he gave me that he says are not working. I had him run [Enable JavaScript](http://www.enable-javascript.com) and [WhatBrowser](http://whatbrowser.org/) websites to get the specs.

> the ipad has JavaScript enabled & Safari Mobile 5 (I purposely don't upgrade as the new one knocks out something i need on the old one). [ does load but slow]
>
> The XP old office computer has JavaScript enabled & IE7 [never loads]
>
> My HP win 7 dual proc 64 bit has JavaScript enabled & IE9 [never loads]
>
> Another XP dual proc 64 bit computer, but only 32 bit XP Home has
>   JavaScript enabled & IE8 [never loads]

Any ideas why it wouldn't be updating the menus on these machines -is there some backwards compatibility issue I'm missing? Seems to be working fine on all of my modern browsers (and IE11's develop in IE7-10 modes all appear to work fine for me).

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/pTKL5/1/

Live site: http://3manchess.com/

Comment: `console.log` if left in could be throwing errors if user doesn't have `console` which isn't uncommon in older IE

Comment: In HTML4 (which is run in older IEs nevertheless the used shims) `id` of an element can start only with a letter or underscore. Your `id`s for colgroups are containing numbers only.

Comment: @charlietfl you are fantastic. I removed `console.log` and he said it works perfectly. Thanks for pointing it out! Make an answer below and I'll mark it as right.

Comment: @Teemu good point! I'll swap that out too (although it looks like `console.log` was the main culprit in this case). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving `console.log` calls in code can cause errors to be thrown in browsers that don't have any `console` installed. This would include IE7 and IE8 unless user had installed developer tools which wasn't available for all versions of IE

There are numerous wrappers or shims available that you can add to your code that will check if `console` exists and if not handle it without errors